# unity 5 C# Object Translation and Rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, transform, unity-game-engine, translate

In unity I am aware how to translate and rotate an object and I always do it in the Update function, the problem I am having is that I want a series of translations and rotations to happen in sequence but the only translation/rotation that occurs is the one that I call first in the code, is there any way to do a translation, wait a certain amount of time and then carry out another translation for example. Thanks.

```
void Update () 
    {

        if (enemyHit == false)
        {
            //enemy moving
            transform.LookAt(TTarget);


        }
        else if (enemyHit == true)
        {
            Debug.Log (enemyHit);

            Evade();
        }
    }
IEnumerator Wait(float duration)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    }

void Evade()
    {

        enemyHit = playerMovement.hitEnemy;

        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        Wait(2);
        transform.Rotate(0,90,0);

    }
```

I tried using a seperate function but that didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Can you add some code please? `the only one that occurs is the first in the code...`?

Comment: do not wait in the update function!!!! you have to check the ElapsedTime since the last update to do such actions

Comment: it wasnt neccesarily wait, I just wanted to do an action and when a condition was met do another action, code below;

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator Wait()
{
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

You may want to start a CoRoutine as well.

```
StartCoroutine("Wait");
```

This should allow you to achieve what you're trying to do.